# Реализация вывода нужных тегов

Tags: php, wordpress

```html
<div class="main-row" id="page-footer">
            <?php if (config('ft_tags')) { echo $app->make(Layout::class)->get('Tagcloud@footer'); } ?>
        </div>
```

^ Есть код, который выводит все элементы из файла Tagcloud

```html
<?php

namespace Components;

use Controllers\Controller;

class Tagcloud extends Controller {

   public function footer() {
      $data = '<ul class="bottom-tagcloud">';
      foreach ($this->sql->orderBy('keyword')->get('tags', 15) as $tag) {
         $keyword = $tag["keyword"];
         $data  .= '<li><a href="tag/'.addLine($keyword).'">'.$keyword.'</a></li>';
      }
      $data .= '</ul>';
      return $data;
   }

}
```

^
Есть файл Tagcloud. Вопрос: как реализовать фильтрацию поступающих тегов для вывода в div таким образом, чтобы выводились только теги, прописанные для файлов при загрузке на сервер?

Comment: "прописанные для файлов при загрузке на сервер" - скажите понятнее, что это за условие.

Comment: Перефразирую: функция footer() создаёт <ul class="bottom-tagcloud">, который, в свою очередь делает в запрос sql и строчкой foreach ($this->sql->orderBy('keyword')->get('tags', 15) as $tag) мы видим присваивание элементов по запросу sql->orderBy('(RAND ())')->get('tags',15) as $tag и в строку разработчика выводятся ссылки в <ul class="bottom-tagcloud"> => <li></li> <li><a href="tag/43284324 ...></a></li> ... так же как и здесь: $keyword = $tag["keyword"];
         $data  .= '<li><a href="tag/'.addLine($keyword).'">'.$keyword.'</a></li>'; В итоге возвращается готовый список </ul>